# Entity Framework - Entity property defaults to object on addition

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm using Entity Framework 6, with the Devart's dotConnect for SQLite provider.

I'm having this (strange ?) behavior:
I'm adding objects to the `OrderItems` collection, with the `Payment` property set to **null**, as in this screenshot (I'm using OzCode)

[image: Screenshot 1]

when I add an item to the `Payments` `DbSet`, an item from my `OrderItems`DbSet automatically (defaults ?) to that `Payment`, as in the following screenshot:

[image]

Why am I having this behavior ? And how can I fix it ?

---

**EDIT:** Here is my [Payments Class](http://gist.github.com/anonymous/ea96bfa518eb5b49704d65ed7d805604)

Comment: Could you show the 'Payments' class, please?

Comment: Here it is: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ea96bfa518eb5b49704d65ed7d805604

Comment: are you not setting payment when you're creating a new order in your code yourself? Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: I only added this line  `item.Payment = null;` for investigation, it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: When you call `_entities.Payments.AddPayment(payment);` that `payment` instance - does it have a reference to first `OrderItem` from `orderItems` collection? I see from the class definition that both Payment and OrderItem have links to each other, so you set one end of relationship but not the other and when insert happens, entity framework does that for you. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it's not the case. The payment instance is initialized with just the customerID and the amount. (It's hidden by the debugger window, sorry), `Payment` have no reference to any `OrderItem` at that point. This is puzzling.